# jQuery .on click only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a rating system for my website.
I am very new to jQuery and don't quite understand why the .on click only running once. It should run every time i click the #ratenumbers2.
Also if you have any other suggestion on how to simplify or write this code a bit tighter i would really appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function fade_out() {$("#votersmessage").fadeOut(4000);}


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ratenumbers").on("click", "#ratenumbers2", function () {
    document.getElementById("votersmessage").innerHTML = "You can only rate once";
    setTimeout(fade_out, 2000);
  });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$usersrating = 5; //I just added this for testing purposes
if(!$usersrating)
  {echo"
  <span id='ratetitle'>Your rating:</span><span id='ratenumbers'> 
  <span id='rate1' onmouseover='rate1()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate2' onmouseover='rate2()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate3' onmouseover='rate3()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate4' onmouseover='rate4()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate5' onmouseover='rate5()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate6' onmouseover='rate6()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate7' onmouseover='rate7()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  <span id='rate8' onmouseover='rate8()' onmouseout='rateblanc()'>&#9734;</span>
  </span>";}
else
  {
  echo"
  <span id='ratetitle'>Your rating:</span><span id='ratenumbers'><span id='ratenumbers2'>";
  if($usersrating == 1){echo" &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 2){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 3){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 4){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 5){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 6){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 7){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734; ";}
  if($usersrating == 8){echo" &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; ";}
  echo"</span></span>";
  }
?>
<span id='ratingend'></span>
<span id='votersmessage'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: ´document.getElementById("votersmessage").innerHTML = "You can only rate once";´ === $('#votersmessage').html("You can only rate once");

Comment: If you prepare a http://plnkr.co others can help faster which makes it easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after `fadeOut()` you don't show the `$("#votersmessage")` again.
Maybe something like

```
$("#ratenumbers").on("click", "#ratenumbers2", function () {
    $("#votersmessage").html("You can only rate once");
    $("#votersmessage").show(); //or fadeIn() for some class
    setTimeout(fade_out, 2000);
});
```

Comment: You mean after it fades out i cannot run it again?

Comment: Yes you can but the `span` is already hidden after the first `fadeOut`, you can't you hide something that is already hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Because the message is never displayed after the first `fadeOut`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ratenumbers").on("click", "#ratenumbers2", function () {
    $("#votersmessage").fadeIn(500).html("You can only rate once");
    setTimeout(function(){$("#votersmessage").fadeOut(4000);}, 2000);
  });
});
```